# Why is jquery script taking forever?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and running a script on my homepage that determines the number of lines in a container (i.e. div).  If the number of lines is over 3 or 4 lines (depending on whether div class is "threeline" or "fourline"), it will truncate it and add an ellipsis.  However, this script is taking forever to execute so I'm wondering why or how it can be optimized.  I've tried to wrap my head around javascript/jquery, but it truly is a foreign language to me!

Can someone please take a look at this script and let me know how I can edit it to make it faster?  Is it unnecessarily checking all elements on the page?

Here is how it is called on my php page:

```
    <div class="bubble left">
    <div class="rounded">
            <blockquote class="ellipsis fourline">
                    <h3><a href="http://www.xyz.com">This is the title</a></h3>

                    <p>This is the body of the quote; if the body plus title is more than fourlines, then the text will be truncated and an ellipsis will be added</p>
            </blockquote>
    </div>
    <cite class="rounded">March 18, 2010</cite>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/js/jquery.ellipsis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(".ellipsis").ellipsis(); </script>
```

And this is the jquery.ellipsis.js file:

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.ellipsis = function()
        {
                return this.each(function()
                {
                        var el = $(this);

                        if(el.css("overflow") == "hidden" && el.hasClass('fourline'))
                        {
                                var text = el.html();
                                var fourline = el.hasClass('fourline');
                                var t = $(this.cloneNode(true))
                                        .hide()
                                        .css('position', 'absolute')
                                        .css('overflow', 'visible')
                                        .width(fourline ? el.width() : 'auto')
                                        .height(fourline ? 'auto' : el.height())
                                        ;

                                el.after(t);

                                function height() { return t.height() > el.height(); };
                                function width() { return t.width() > el.width(); };

                                var func = fourline ? height : width;

                                while (text.length > 0 && func())
                                {
                                        text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
                                        t.html(text + "&hellip;");
                                }

                                el.html(t.html());
                                t.remove();
                        } else if (el.css("overflow") == "hidden" && el.hasClass('threeline'))
                        {
                                var text = el.html();
                                var threeline = el.hasClass('threeline');
                                var t = $(this.cloneNode(true))
                                        .hide()
                                        .css('position', 'absolute')
                                        .css('overflow', 'visible')
                                        .width(threeline ? el.width() : 'auto')
                                        .height(threeline ? 'auto' : el.height())
                                        ;

                                el.after(t);

                                function height() { return t.height() > el.height(); };
                                function width() { return t.width() > el.width(); };

                                var func = threeline ? height : width;

                                while (text.length > 0 && func())
                                {
                                        text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
                                        t.html(text + "&hellip;");
                                }

                                el.html(t.html());
                                t.remove();
                        }
                });
        };
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance, I love this site!

Answer (score 0):

Tough to say given there is lots of code there.

I'd consider using a profiler, such as the Firebug profiler to determine what is hitting you the hardest.

http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Profiling

Off the top of my head I'd guess it has something to do with the while iterations, and the fact you are chaining multiple functions during them. Profiling will give you a better picture though.

Comment: Setup firebug and enabled console and profiler, but when I reload the page, nothing appears.  Added console.profile() and console.profileEnd() to my code but I still get nothing.  Is it because I'm in a development environment and firebug is checking the live version of my homepage?

Comment: I don't even think you need to insert any code. Load up your page, open the console, enable the "Persist" button, click profile. Profiler is now running. Load your page again. Click profile a second time to turn it off. You should now see the results.

Comment: And yes, it will only profile the code on the page in the browser, so you have to make sure the browser is loading a current copy of your script. You may wish to combine firebug with the web developer toolbar for firefox and disable the browser cache through it's cache options to ensure you're always dealing with live pages/data.

Comment: I had to reinstall firebug, I must have had an older version.  The new install works now... now just trying to understand the report.

Answer (score 0):

i'm pretty sure it's this:

```
while (text.length > 0 && func())
{
        text = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
        t.html(text + "&hellip;");
}
```

it looks like your looping while you still have text, taking a character off and putting it in a div.  if you have a lot of characters this is going to take a while.

why not use a plugin?

there is a pretty good discussion about this here:
http://devongovett.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/text-overflow-ellipsis-for-firefox-via-jquery/

for IE, Safari and Chrome you can just set the text-overflow to ellipsis and it'll take care of it for you.

Comment: I actually grabbed this script from one of the comments on that blog because I needed multiple lines.  I'll play around with the length of text and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: i thought it looked familiar!